# M2: Payment captured - order not in Magento (paypal, cybersource)

Tags: magento2, payment, payment-gateway, paypal-express, credit-card

I have some payments captured but cannot find the related orders in Magento.

This happens with both, paypal and cybersource payments.

I can personally reproduce it by placing a payment and interrupting the redirect back to Magento by closing the browser.

Obviously, this situation is not bearable - neither from a customer's, nor from the business's perspective. What can I do to solve it?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.2.7. I am also facing this issue. Which log to refer to find out the issue. I use Razor Pay.

Comment: So far, I have not found a way to log these issues. We compare transactions lists from the payment provider with orders on a daily base. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this issue in Magento2. This is happening while trying to create an order in Magento after payment is taken by the payment provider such as Cybersource. In my case this is happening because the product goes to OOS (Out of Stock) due to other customers' purchases or stock updates while the customer is adding the payment details on the external page of the payment provider. We have frequent stock updates, and that could cause products going OOS in any step of checkout process. However, there could be different reasons for others that fails validation before placing order in Magento. For me this was happening in below file:

`src/vendor/cybersource/module-secure-acceptance/Controller/Index/PlaceOrder.php`

in below line:

`$order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);`

The solution could be we should cancel the order in payment provider and refund once the order validation/creation is failed. I am still trying to check how this can be achieved. Please suggest if anyone has some better solution for this issue.